# How to Open, Evaluate and Close the same Notebook 100 times in a row?

Tags: front-end, programming, evaluation

I have a Mathematica notebook which I Open and Evaluate by hand. It Exports some data and then Closes.

I now wanna Open, Run and Close the exact same Notebook 100 or 1000 times in a row to get a lot of data.

How to do program Mathematica to do this operation for me?

Comment: @Moo, the notebook does a calculation which depends on random numbers. I need to run the same notebook many, many times to generate a lot of data

Comment: @Moo What I would like is to reproduce the calculation of one notebook many times. To do that, I want to open, run and close the same notebook 10000 times in a row. Is it possible in mathematica?

Comment: @Moo I see. Do you know if it is possible to open, run and close the same Mathematica notebook 100 times in a row?

Comment: Why not just run the calculation as many times as you want within the notebook?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Because of the specifics of the calculation this is not so easy. Do you know if it is possible to open, run and close the same Mathematica notebook 100 times in a row?

Comment: Why is it not so easy?

Comment: @Nigel1 you can turn your code into a package, generally with very little trouble. After you've done that, calling a package many, many times is very, very easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that Rohit is correct that there is probably a better way than executing repeatedly from an external notebook, but here is one way to do it. First, create your notebook. For testing, I created the following in a notebook called randInt.nb. This does a random calculation and then saves a file.

```
r = RandomInteger[10];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "test" <> 
  ToString[RandomInteger[10000]] <> ".txt", r]
```

To call and execute this repeatedly, create a notebook called test.nb which has contents:

```
Table[NotebookEvaluate[NotebookDirectory[] <> "randInt.nb"], {i, 5}]
```

This executes the code in randInt.nb 5 times, as can be verified because it creates 5 text files.